# Project Jhipster 4 runs good but after create entity its run but the page is empty

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript, webpack, jhipster

Itry to run this project 
https://github.com/JinnaBalu/jhipster4-mongodb
it is run good but after generating an entity using " yo jhipster:entity " 
i try to run , there is no any error but the browser page is empty .
Please Help

Comment: Look at browser's console

Comment: There is no any error in the console

Comment: jhipster 4 is not yet released and mongodb is not our highest priority, I would recommend you wait for release or try sql db first

Comment: Did you run `npm link generator-jhipster` in your project before generating your entity?

Comment: yes , i did . please take a look at this project . it works before generating an entity on ts but when i  generate entity on ts there a lot of errors when i tape ./mvn . here is the console :                                                                                                   ./mvnw
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i deleted the answer i am sorry i new at posting in stack .please take a look at the project if you have time and if there is any error that you can correct it . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem there, bug or incompatibility.

I faced this problem too. On two occasions:

1. JHipster would empty my index.html, then I would have to revert the file and run `yarn install` again.
2. I had to face a weird issue with png files, due to a bug in pngquant, the error is yielded by a npm build, I had to delete `node_modules`folder and run `yarn install` again.